# Add a price with the chosen quantity - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a function that takes all the prices from the products in the shopping card and multiply the price with the from the user chosen quantity.

At first I build this function :

```
function calculate() {
    var total = 0;
    var priceCells = document.getElementsByClassName("priceCell");
    for (var i = 0; i < priceCells.length; i++) {
        var thisPrice = priceCells[i].innerHTML;
        var quantity = document.getElementsByClassName("quantity")[i].value;
        thisPrice = thisPrice * quantity;
        total = total + thisPrice;
    }
    total = total.toFixed(2);
}
```

This gives me the price from all products multiplied with the chosen quantity.

This is great and works perfect.

What I need now is a similar function ( like: calculateSinglePrice ) that gives me the price for the single product multiplied with the chosen quantity the user want from this specific product.

Like:

```
// my table
<table bla bla bla>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="priceCell">
            50$
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" class="form-control text-center quantity" min="1" max="999" value="4"> // the user has choose 4 
        </td>
        <td>
            // I want to output here the first result
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="priceCell">
            20$
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" class="form-control text-center quantity" min="1" max="999" value="5"> // the user has choose 5
        </td>
        <td>
            // I want to output here the seccond result
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="priceCell">
            5$
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" class="form-control text-center quantity" min="1" max="999" value="10"> // the user has choose 10
        </td>
         <td>
            // I want to output here the third result
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Result I want to have:

```
    totalitem[0] = 200$ // Result from  50$ * 4 ;
    totalitem[1] = 100$ // Result from  20$ * 5 ;
    totalitem[2] = 50$ // Result from  5€$ * 10 ;
```

How do I get that? I'm still new to javascript..

I get all the different prices with:

```
var priceCells = document.getElementsByClassName("priceCell");
```

I get the quantity the user has choosen inside a foreach loop with:

```
var quantity = document.getElementsByClassName("quantity")[i].value;
```

Jquery is allowed. I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can simply attach a `change` and `paste` event handler to the `.quantity` elements which then loops through them all to create an array with the product line totals. Try this:

```js
$('.quantity').on('change', getTotals);

function getTotals() {
  var totals = $('.quantity').map(function() {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    return parseFloat($tr.find('.priceCell').text()) * parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
  }).get();
  
  console.log(totals);
}

getTotals(); // on load
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table bla bla bla>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="priceCell">50$</td>
    <td><input type="number" class="form-control text-center quantity" min="1" max="999" value="4"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="priceCell">20$</td>
    <td><input type="number" class="form-control text-center quantity" min="1" max="999" value="5"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="priceCell">5$</td>
    <td><input type="number" class="form-control text-center quantity" min="1" max="999" value="10"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow, this works like a charm and is way more better then my tries... The map method is new to me..  Is there a way to get my calucalte function  a bit more efficient?

Comment: Glad to help. With regard to optimising, there's not much you can do really. All you're doing is multiplying two numbers. You could use a `data` attribute to avoid having to cast the values to float/int, but that's only minor. Certainly not a performance concern.

Comment: thanks! this also works :) I've updated the HTML section in my question. Please have a look. I want to output each result in a third <td>* output *</td> ?

Comment: I saw - that's quite different from your original problem. You should really start a new question for that.

Comment: Well you're right, thanks anyway! I will try it first on my own :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

I have made a function named `calculateSinglePrice()` and it calculates the total price of each row.

```js
calculateSinglePrice();
function calculate() {
    var total = 0;
    var priceCells = document.getElementsByClassName("priceCell");
    for (var i = 0; i < priceCells.length; i++) {
        var thisPrice = priceCells[i].innerHTML;
        var quantity = document.getElementsByClassName("quantity")[i].value;
        thisPrice = thisPrice * quantity;
        total = total + thisPrice;
    }
    total = total.toFixed(2);
}

function calculateSinglePrice()
{

    var priceCells = document.getElementsByClassName("priceCell");
      for (var i = 0; i < priceCells.length; i++) {
      var total = 0;
        var thisPrice = priceCells[i].innerHTML;
        thisPrice = thisPrice.substring(0, thisPrice.indexOf('$'));
        var quantity = document.getElementsByClassName("quantity")[i].value;
        thisPrice = thisPrice * quantity;
        total = total + thisPrice;
  
       console.log(total + '$');
    }
    
 
}
```

```html
<table bla bla bla>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="priceCell">
            50$
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" class="form-control text-center quantity" min="1" max="999" value="4"> 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="priceCell">
            20$
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" class="form-control text-center quantity" min="1" max="999" value="5"> 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="priceCell">
            5$
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" class="form-control text-center quantity" min="1" max="999" value="10"> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks! this also works :) I've updated the HTML section in my question. Please have a look. I want to output each result in a third <td>* output *</td> ?